# Display a message inside Android Edit Text Field

Tags: android, field, android-edittext

Hai,
I have an Android Program with one text field.
I need to display a message inside that textfield when it loads on an emulator.
When the user clicks inside that textbox that message should dispappear. 
For Ex: Please enter name
Can any one post some sample code over here...

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer, it will help you increase your reputation

Answer (score 12):

Just use or call `setHint` on the object. Hint text to display when the text is empty.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18px"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egestas ullamcorper facilisis." />
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the attribute `Hint` of the EditText.

`android:hint` in your xml
`setHint(int)` at runtime

This will execute just what you need