# Android : How to put a (Hint) link that pops up a window

Tags: android, tooltip, hint

I am developing an Android application and I need to put a link beside a Text Edit in a form.

The link will pop up a window that holds a tool tip for the user.

EDIT : I want to put some sort of a link beside the text field and, when the user clicks on this link, a pop up window appears and tells him how to fill this text field.

How can I do this in Android ?

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: check this link it should be very useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318083/display-a-message-inside-android-edit-text-field

Comment: Thank you for the link but this is not what I want to do.

I want to put some sort of a link beside the text field and when the user clicks on this link a pop up window appears that tells him how to fill this text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "link" can easyly be created by puting a TextView and adding an `OnClickListener`.

About the "popup":

Have you had a look at Toast-messages? They seem to be doing exactly what you want to do.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Context context, String yourMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG/SHORT);
toast.show();
```

If you had, here are some other solutions that could do what you want:

What about a solution with some kind of `Dialog`? Eg. an `AltertDialog` could open up, showing the tip, but the User would have to press "OK" to close the "popup".

Another solution, which is also quite ugly would be playing with visibilities. the "popup" would be present allt he time, but only visible if the link is clicked.
[How to change visibility of layout programaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465841/how-to-change-visibility-of-layout-programaticly)

Answer (score 0):

use `android:hint="Your hint"` for your `EditText` to show hint.

Comment: What if I want to put a link pop up a window that holds a tip for the user ?

Comment: create a dynamic box and fill your hint in that and make sure that for particular region